# AndroidStudio not finding RealmRecyclerViewAdapter - android realm-plugin:2.2.2

Tags: android, realm

AndroidStudio 2.2.3 is failing to resolve my RealmRecyclerViewAdapter reference.  I've followed the RecyclerViewAdaper example straight from the Realm site.  Could someone help me figure out why it's not finding RealmRecyclerViewAdapter?

Here are my import statements:

```
import io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection;
import io.realm.RealmRecyclerViewAdapter; //this fails
```

Here's my project-level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's my application-level gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creditcardcalcx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you're missing the following dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  I figured there was a dependency I was missing, but I didn't see anything called out in their intro documentation.  Do you know if these additional dependencies are called out anywhere in their documentation?

Comment: (although apparently they don't have the [realm android user store](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-user-store) mentioned anywhere, so I guess the documentation isn't complete)